# In Intellij go back command not working every time

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

In Intellij how to go back to the previous line after ctrl-clicking something that takes you to something in the same file.  For example from the code shown below, I ctrl-click myInt in myFunction() and it takes me to the top of the class where myInt is defined.  But now I want to go back to where I was, in myFunction() where myInt is being used.  I used ctrl+alt+leftarrow and it sometimes works but sometimes it goes somewhere else.  Any idea what my issue is or a better hotkey to use?

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static final int myInt = 1_000;
       .
       .
       .
  lots of code
       .
       .
       .
  public void myFunction()
  {
    int newInt = 1 + myInt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was sometimes I didn't get the ctrl+alt+leftarrow combo just right which lead to alt+leftarrow being used which selects the previous tab.  To avoid this issue I'm changing my settings to have ctr+leftarrow be the back command.  Any ideas for a better hotkey for the back command?